# Call isFinishing() or backbuttonpressed?

Tags: android

I want to clear the cache of my activity which downloads photos from a server and uses the [disklrucache](/questions/tagged/disklrucache) and [lrucache](/questions/tagged/lrucache) to store them will my activity is active. I want when the user leaves this activity to clear the caches. So how can i handle this? Is it good solution to check the state of isFinishing() in onPause or should i override the [backpressed](/questions/tagged/backpressed). I know that it is not certain that the isfinishing will be called when the user presses the backbutton!

Comment: clear the cache in onDestory()

Comment: i don't want to clear the cache in orientation change. that's why i have the options i mentioned before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you want the behavior of your application.

If you want to clear the cache when the activity is fiished and now you are storing them in onCreate then

```
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    // clear your cache
}
```

But if you want to clear cache when the user leave the activity that means when it is paused then you should clear the cache in `onPause` method. But at that time you have to store the data in `onResume` method. I think it is a better option to release memory of activiy when it is in background also.

**EDIT:**

From the source code of onKeyDown

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
1801        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
1802            if (getApplicationInfo().targetSdkVersion
1803                    >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR) {
1804                event.startTracking();
1805            } else {
1806                onBackPressed();
1807            }
1808            return true;
1809        }
```

So you can see that if backbutton is pressed then onBackPressed is called. So I think As you need only back button handling so better to override onBackPressed method

Comment: thanks for your response but i want to clear the cache only when the user leaves the activity with back button (activity isfinishing). I don't want to clear the cache in cases of pause, orientation change, home button pressed and onStop cases! That's why i ask which is the best way to handle this. I am not sure but the isFinishing is not certain that it will execute every time the user leaves the activity. As for the backbutton i have to override the onKeydown or the onbackPressed? Finally which is the best way to achieve my goal?

Comment: @user2065529 as you are only focussing backbutton so definitely it is better to override onBakcPressed method .. Except that both are same

Comment: one last thing.As i build my app in gingebird and above i have to only override the onBackPressed and not the onKeyDown. Am i right?